# bower not working (after upgrade to macOS sierra)

Tags: bower

As an example I want to install masonry (from http://masonry.desandro.com) so I type:

```
bower install masonry --save
```

I get

```
bower invalid-meta  The "name" is recommended to be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes
bower not-cached    https://github.com/Aspera/angular-storage.git#~0.5.0
bower resolve       https://github.com/Aspera/angular-storage.git#~0.5.0
bower not-cached    https://github.com/desandro/masonry.git#*
bower resolve       https://github.com/desandro/masonry.git#*
Username for 'https://github.com': bower checkout      masonry#v4.1.1
bower resolved      https://github.com/desandro/masonry.git#4.1.1
bower not-cached    https://github.com/desandro/get-size.git#^2.0.2
bower resolve       https://github.com/desandro/get-size.git#^2.0.2
bower not-cached    https://github.com/metafizzy/outlayer.git#^2.1.0
bower resolve       https://github.com/metafizzy/outlayer.git#^2.1.0
bower checkout      get-size#v2.0.2
bower checkout      outlayer#v2.1.0
bower resolved      https://github.com/desandro/get-size.git#2.0.2
bower resolved      https://github.com/metafizzy/outlayer.git#2.1.0
bower not-cached    https://github.com/metafizzy/fizzy-ui-utils.git#^2.0.0
bower resolve       https://github.com/metafizzy/fizzy-ui-utils.git#^2.0.0
bower not-cached    https://github.com/metafizzy/ev-emitter.git#^1.0.0
bower resolve       https://github.com/metafizzy/ev-emitter.git#^1.0.0
bower checkout      ev-emitter#v1.0.3
bower checkout      fizzy-ui-utils#v2.0.3
bower resolved      https://github.com/metafizzy/ev-emitter.git#1.0.3
bower resolved      https://github.com/metafizzy/fizzy-ui-utils.git#2.0.3
bower not-cached    https://github.com/desandro/matches-selector.git#~2.0.0
bower resolve       https://github.com/desandro/matches-selector.git#~2.0.0
bower checkout      desandro-matches-selector#v2.0.1
bower resolved      https://github.com/desandro/matches-selector.git#2.0.1
```

Then it asks for my password:

```
Password for 'https://github.com': 
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/Aspera/angular-storage.git", exit code of #128 remote: Repository not found. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Aspera/angular-storage.git/'

Additional error details:
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Aspera/angular-storage.git/'
```

What the !*$#! is going on here I didn't want angular-storage
and my password is valid but it didn't give me a chance to enter my username.
I have re-installed bower but it is still messed up. Was fine before I foolishly let macOS Sierra in through the door.

Answer (score 0):

OK herewith the problem:
bower.json contained "angular-storage": "~0.5.0" in the dependencies list but I had deleted angular-storage from bower-components in favour of a0-angular-storage.
Cue erratic behaviour of bower, so obviously when removing items from bower_components one also has to delete the relevant dependency from bower.json.
Also the bower.json had the line:
"private": true
which I removed, and now it no longer asks me to login.